# Stuck at homescreen after new installation

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, cursor

I have a system with one hdd dedicated to window. I bought a **new hdd specifically for ubuntu**, a few days back. I created a live usb with ubuntu on it and started the process to install ubuntu on the new hdd.

There was an option "Try ubuntu without installing". I used that option and was displayed the ubuntu homescreen. But there was some strange thing happening. I was unable to move my cursor or use my keyboard. Cursor was moving a bit once every minute and i was unable to use my keyboard at all.

This was a clear indication of some problem but i still went ahead and installed ubuntu. Now i am facing the same problem. I am kind of **stuck at the homescreen. Unable to use my keyboard or mouse.** Whereas my older hdd with windows on it is running perfectly, on the same pc.

Can anyone here help me troubleshoot the problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem since installing 14.04, except the mouse and keyboard work fine until you log into your desktop. When I put password in then the problem happens. There is a work around, if your force it to go into recovery mode while booting up it will allow you to use mouse and keyboard. The screen size is not correct but at least it will allow you to run. Mouse and keyboard work fine before you get into your desktop, definitely an Ubuntu 14.04 problem as new installation. Have another computer that is dual booted and it does not have the mouse problems. Updated that from 12 though, not new install.

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Update on above answer I have SOLVED this issue by using the updater icon in system settings. Appears hat the problem is related to the settings that Ubuntu uses on its original install. The settings did not update with Canonical updates and also propitiatory drivers.

I don't know what the problem was but making the changes allowed everything to work without problems. Now it is very enjoyable to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but i removed this version after banging my head with it. Just went back to the older version of ubuntu. I will surely try your wayout if i install this version again in the future.